# Should authentication be in a separate service for wcf?

Tags: wcf

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398990.aspx) on `msdn`, it tells you to set the Service attribute of the `.svc file` to `System.Web.ApplicationServices.AuthenticationService`, but then I can't use it for my service library, so is it pretty much saying that if I want to use `authentication` this way, I should keep it separate from my service?  How would I use my authentication service in my own service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Authentication service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386582.aspx) exposes ASP.NET membership as SOAP service. It has no relation to custom WCF services. Custom WCF services use membership API directly via [user name authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731049.aspx).

Comment: Well, I was looking at this:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386455.aspx and it says before I do this I must enable AuthenticationServices which is what the link in my post is about.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Authentication service is used to authenticate clients in external application with membership API. For example you can create winform application and use authentication service to authenticate users. But if you want authenticate client in your service you don't need it.

Comment: Here is my scenario, I have users in a table called Users and this  table contains the username and an encrypted password and I want to authenticate the user before he/she can access my service.

Comment: So you need custom user name validator: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702565.aspx and not authentication service.

Comment: Yes, I have done this approach, but they also mentioned how to do it with a Custom Membership Provider.  By custom, did they mean that you would implement the Membership Provider?

Comment: Yes, custom membership provider means that you implement new membership provider.